# Unable to implement computed property override on UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios-extensions

When trying to implement this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public var presentedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIViewController()
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:
`.../ExampleApp/ExampleAppTests/SpecExtensions.swift:41:59: Getter for 'presentedViewController' with Objective-C selector 'presentedViewController' conflicts with method 'presentedViewController()' with the same Objective-C selector`

I'm using the same selector that UIViewController.h defines:
`public var presentedViewController: UIViewController? { get }`

Is the error misleading or am I just overlooking something? I've tried it with and without `override`, `public`, as a method, etc.  No luck.  However, I am able to override it if it's on a subclass of UIViewController, but not UIViewController itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have it in an extension. You can't override methods that were defined on a class from an extension. Basically an extension is not a sub-class, trying to redefine methods that exist on a class by implementing a new version in an extension will fail.

Note that this works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var presentedViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIViewController()
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does this work then?:

    class ViewControllerSubclass: UIViewController {
    }

    extension ViewControllerSubclass {
        override var presentedViewController: UIViewController? {
            return UIViewController()
        }
    }

Comment: I'm having the hardest time getting code to format in my response above.  Maybe it's not possible; Sorry it's so hard to read.

Comment: No problem... That works because you have the extension in the same file in which the class is defined, so the compiler treats it as part of the `class`. If you move that extension to a separate file, it won't compile either.

Comment: It's actually still working if I move the extension to a different file.

Comment: Sorry, my first explanation was wrong... Put it in both your sub-class and the extension. Then it won't work. You can't use extensions to override methods that already exist in a class. `presentedViewController` already exists in `UIViewController`. Since you didn't define it in `ViewControllerSubclass` you were able to override it in the extension.

Comment: Fixed answer with better explanation.